# How to pass data from Navigation Component to Home Component in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, navigation

The components in my React app are as follows.
-App.js
-NavbarComponent
-HomeComponent
-FooterComponent

I want to create an Onclick method where when a user clicks on the buttons of navbar, the page glides to that particular div. And also when the user scrolls to a div, the button with the same name is highlighted.

Comment: Try to post some code with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can implement your requirements

1. Using Redux (prefered way)

Just maintain the state for you app in redux. you can store the current visible div name in redux and then from `HomeComponent` subscribe to this redux state.

2. Local Component state in App component

You can maintain a local state in App component and then pass this local state and its callback function to update this state down to `NavbarComponent` and `HomeComponent`.

Lets take example of functional component

```
const [currentVisibleState,setCurrentVisibleState] = useState("");
```

Now just pass this below to both the components `NavbarComponent` & `HomeComponent`

```
<NavbarComponent 
  currentVisibleState={currentVisibleState} 
  setCurrentVisibleState={setCurrentVisibleState}
/>
```

And to scroll down to a div you can make use of the `scrollIntoView` function